# How to swap a Django ManytoMany relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a situation where two models have been previously created:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField('Publication')
    
class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

and now due to a change in how these models are being used, I need to move the ManyToManyField over to the other model, to hopefully end up with:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Publication(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    publishers = models.ManyToManyField('Publisher')
```

while maintaining the existing relations between the two models. Is this possible? I've tried swapping the relation over but the migration that is generated only removes the field from the old model, which doesn't seem right. How can I preserve the ManyToMany link when I move the field from one Model to the other?

Comment: Why do you need to swap these: you can query `ManyToManyField`s in a bi-directional way.

Comment: My boss says it 'doesn't read correctly' from a business logic perspective, so he wants it moved.

Comment: you can use `related_name=...` (and `related_query_name=...`) to specify the name of the relation in reverse (and for querying). Since the items are stored in a junction table, and not in any of the tables of these models, that thus means that it makes no difference in the database either.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that a bit? Are you saying that adding `related_name='publications'` on the field should be enough? I've just tried it, but trying to access publishers afterwards returns `'Publication' object has no attribute 'publisher_set'`

Comment: @icognito2me: no `related_name='publishers'`. Then you can access the m2m from a publication as `mypublication.publishers`, so not `publisher_set`...

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not being clear. I was accessing via the mypublication.publishers format. I have just tried moving to `related_name='publishers'` but unfortunately still get the same error `'Publication' object has no attribute 'publisher_set'`